# GNU Make fails to enter subdirectories from a loop

Tags: c, linux, makefile, gnu-make

I have a project with several subdirectories, the main Makefile needs to be able to build/clean some of the subdirectories - the exact names of the subdirectories are passed in a variable (DIRS in the example):

```
DIRS = dir1 dir2 # Usually passed from the command line

.PHONY: all clean $(DIRS)

all: $(DIRS)
    # ... do stuff in this direcotry ...

$(DIRS):
    $(MAKE) -C $(@)

clean:
    # ... Clean this directory ...
    $(foreach d,$(DIRS),cd $(d) && $(MAKE) clean; )
```

Since I am already using the directories names as a build target, I want to use a loop for cleaning each subdirectory. But I get the following error:

```
$ make clean
# ... Clean this directory ...
cd dir1 && make clean;  cd dir2 && make clean;
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ex/clean_try/dir1'
rm -fr *.o
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ex/clean_try/dir1'
/bin/sh: 1: cd: can't cd to dir2
make: *** [clean] Error 2
```

It seems like it's already leaving dir1, how come it can't enter dir2 from the main directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cd dir2` is in the context of having just done `cd dir1` --- and dir2 is not a subdirectory of dir1, right ? :-)

Try:  `make -C $d clean`

HTH

Comment: OK, that did the trick. But... how come it says: `Leaving directory '/home/ex/clean_try/dir1'` before the error? That's baffling, to say the least...

Comment: That is normal make-within-make behaviour. Suppressable with `--no-print-directory`